# Classe MPDF - Imagens Base64

Tags: imagem, mpdf, base64

boa tarde, estou utilizando uma classe mdpf para gerar o PDF de um arquivo, só que, ao utilizar uma imagem em base64 dentro de um `<img>` do modelo minha imagem não apareceu [image: Ela fica dessa forma]

Função:

```
    $date = date("dmYHi");
    $mpdf = new mPDF('','A4',0,'',10,5,7,7,6,6,'L');
    $mpdf->charset_in='windows-1252';
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($modelo);
    $mpdf->Output("boletos/orcamentopdf_".$date.$_GET['id'].".pdf");
```

Alguém sabe me informar uma forma de corrigir isso ou de gravar o modelo com a imagem no BD?

Obs.: Quando gero pelo navegador sai tudo certinho e beleza! Só usando essa função que buga!

Comment: Sua tag da imagem está assim? `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, ...código gigante..." >`

Comment: Exatamente! `<img src="data:image/png;base64, ... >` só muda a extensão!